# Python CSV read row by row and insert new data

Tags: python

I have a csv file, from which I will read row by row and for certain field the data need to be processed and insert the results into another field in the same row before moving on to the next field.

I tried various methods like:

```
w = open('test.csv', 'w+')
csv_r = csv_reader(w)
csv_w = csv.writer(w)

for row in csv_r:
    row[10] = results
    csv_w.writerows(row)
```

But I am getting blank. Is there any other way doing this?

Basically i need to read a specific element in a row and then process the data and the result will be appended into another element in the same row.

Comment: how many rows does `csv_r` have initially? Also, how can you be sure that results in not empty(or null) ?

Comment: @anand-s-kumar should be around 20+ rows. And the results will not be null, as I will check if null insert "empty" string as the results

Comment: there is no way from what you have provided that you should get an empty csv file once `csv_r` is not empty

Comment: @PadraicCunningham But I am writing using csv_w

Comment: what is `w` supposed to be in `csv_r = csv_reader(w)`?

Comment: I am guessing he meant to open writer on the `r` file (since he is openning that is write mode)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry my mistake, it is a typo. I have edited it already.

Comment: @aandroidtest,  you are truncating the file as pointed out in my answer, you should use a tempfile when updating a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are openning both reader and writer on the same file -

```
csv_r = csv_reader(w)
csv_w = csv.writer(w)
```

Is that expected? Shouldn't you be openning them on different files?

If you intentionally did it, try using different files, when you open a file with `w+` mode, if the file exists it gets overwritten.

> w+    Opens a file for both writing and reading. Overwrites the existing file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new file for reading and writing.

Try openning the file with `r+` mode.

Comment: Meaning I make a copy and open them concurrently to make the changes?

Comment: no, open the file you want to read in reader, and then open a completely new file in the writer, and then make your changes to lines from reader and writer them into the new csv.

Comment: Then if you want to move the new file to overwrite old file use - `import shutil; shutil.move('<oldname>','<newname>')`

Answer (score 2):

`w+` empties/truncates your file so you have nothing to iterate over. It is `r+` for reading and writing.

To update the file either store all the updated rows, reopen the file and write or a much better approach is use a [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) to write to then replace the original with shutil.move.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move
import csv


with open("test.csv") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",dir=".", delete=False) as temp:   
    # write all updated rows to out tempfile
    csv_w = csv.writer(out)
    csv_r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_r:
       row[10] = results
       csv_w.writerows(row)
# replace original file with updated
move(temp.name,"test.csv")
```